# How to bulk document delete in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am very new Alfresco user. We have uploaded 18000 documents to Alfresco. Then we noticed that some categories are not correct. We would like to upload them again, but we don't know how to delete existing documents. Is there any way to delete all documents that were uploaded yesterday?

Comment: Are you looking to do it through the Share UI, through Java, JavaScript, CIFS, WebDAV, CMIS? Any of those? None of those?

Comment: Any of those. Preferably easiest way.

Comment: Share UI would be best option for us as we don't want to touch code base.

Comment: Using any of the APIs, or one of the protocols involves no changes to the codebase either!

Comment: ok, can you give me more details how. (or document link). If you write it as a post, I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

The best way is to use a code based method (JavaScript or CMIS).
So, the easiest way is to create a JavaScript file in Data Dictionary/Script folder
with something like this:

```
    // execute a lucene search across the repository for pdf documents in a specific folder created the exact day
   var docs = search.luceneSearch("PATH:\"/app:company_home/cm:myFolder//*\" AND @cm\\:content.mimetype:\"application/pdf\" AND @cm\\:created:2013-05-21");
   var i;
   for (i=0; i<docs.length; i++)
   {
   docs[i].remove();
   }
```

although 18k documents could probably create some memory issues in your JVM.

Maybe the script will interrupt at some point, and you'll have to restart the machine and execute script again.

Comment: sorry, it might be silly question but, do I need to replace "company_home" and "myFolder" keyword. If yes, are those values in config file?

Comment: Company home is the root alfresco directory..myFolder is an example..you should put the values of your dir path where you want the script to be deleting files..remember that company_home goes with app: prefix and the other folders with cm: prefix..

Comment: that's a pretty sweet answer

Answer (score 0):

I would use the WebDAV to delete that.

First, from a window running PC. I would add a network place for the webDAV of alfresco.

Then from Window explorer, I will delete very easily like as deleting folders/files in window.

You can google for webDAV api URL to add.